# Accessing a remote machine & grep multiple string pattern from file in Unix platform

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ssh

> I am facing an issue when I try "egrep" or "grep -e" with multiple
>   string patterns in Remote machine.

For example :
Consider the hostmachine as server1 .

- *The following works with single pattern:*

  **ssh server1 grep "STRING1" /tmp/file.txt**
- *The following with multiple patterns doesn't work get the following error:*

  **ssh server1 egrep "STRING1|STRING2" /tmp/file.txt**

  bash: STRING2: command not found

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work by just replacing the dobule quote with single quote and surrounding with double quotes the whole command

```
ssh server1 "egrep 'STRING1|STRING2' /tmp/file.txt"
```

It is usually a good idea to enclose the command you want to run on remote host in quotes or here-docs in order to avoid character interpolation by the local bash interpreter

Comment: thanks @Andrea Binda . This worked perfectly for me :)

Answer (score -2):

The following should work

`ssh server1 "grep -E 'STRING1|STRING2' /tmp/file.txt"`

`-E`:  Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular  expression.

EDIT: My initial answer were wrong due to the local shell removing the quotes around the quoted string before passing it on to the remote shell as explained by @tripleee , I also removed the `-P` because it's not portable.

Comment: Hi @ZeppRock, both dint work . getting this "bash: STRING2: command not found".

Comment: @sarav What version of grep are you using? you can check with `grep --version`

Comment: .I am using "grep (GNU grep) 2.20" .

Comment: This is unrelated to the `grep` version. The problem is that the local shell removes the quotes around the quoted string before passing it on to the remote shell. (And recommending `grep -P` is just bad advice here; it's not portable, and doesn't simplify anything or expose useful features for this particular use case.)